# How to tee to stderr? (multiple sinks in one pipeline)

Tags: linux, bash, stderr, tee

```
some_source | (tee /dev/stderr | sink_1) 2>&1 | sink_2
```

Seems to fail.

How to do it right without of any temporaries?

Comment: In what way is it failing. I get the same result for your example, grawity's answer and for `some_source | { tee /dev/stderr | sink_1; } 2>&1 | sink_2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
some_source | tee >(sink_1) | sink_2
```

`>( )` is [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).